# Azure Credentials for build server

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm having authentication headaches with Azure.  I have a continuous build server running powershell scripts, and I'm getting messages like:

> Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRMAccount to set up your Azure credentials.

I don't like having to login with my account on the build server.  I suppose I could create another account just for building, but that will expire as well.  Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. Maybe you could a user for build server and grant restricted permissions. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-assignments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use Login-AzureRmAccount in your build/deploy scripts because this is an interactive login, but rather [`Add-AzureRmAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.profile/v2.5.0/add-azurermaccount) instead.

Add-AzureRmAccount requires you [create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) (application) in Azure AD and use its client id and secret/key to authenticate.

Here is a code snippet that you can use:

```
$clientID = "<the client id of your AD Application>"
$key = "<the key of your AD Application>"
$SecurePassword = $key | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -argumentlist $clientID, $SecurePassword

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -ServicePrincipal
```

To find out you tenant id (single subscription)

```
$tenant = (Get-AzureRmSubscription).TenantId
```

Find tenant id (multiple subscriptions)

```
$tenant = (Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "My Subscription").TenantId
```

Comment: Based on my knowledge, `login-Azurermaccount` also could non-interactive login. Please refer to this [link](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Non-Interactive-Azure-Resource-Manager-Login/).

Comment: Well, maybe it supports one scenario of non-interactive login, but the other command is actually designed for that purpose. So it represents a better choice in this scenario

Comment: If OP only wants to login with non-interactive login, it is a correct answer. However, Microsoft account(such as *@hotmail) does not support non-interactive login.

Comment: Does this mean I need to create an "Azure ActiveDirectory" first?  (btw, how do you get notifications when I add comments here? Or do you?)

Comment: Every Azure subscription will have a default Active Directory, you just need to go to its management blade and add an application. I get notifications as I'm using the iOS app for StackOverflow

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I think OP has mentioned he will use the script in a build server (continuous build) which is an unattended execution by convention. This means my answer here is purposed to his specific scenario.

Comment: For anyone watching this, you need to goto "app registration" and add a Web/API.  The URL doesn't do anything in this case, but you have to put something.  You use need to use the app id AND create a key for the app, which serves as your password.  The code above works nicely with these values.  I'll try and add an answer to show what I did later